# sbt package is trying to download a package whose path does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

These are the contents of my build.sbt file:

```
name := "WordCounter"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
)
```

when I try to run `sbt package` this is the output that I get

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.13:2.4.5
[error] not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.13/2.4.5/spark-core_2.13-2.4.5.pom
```

If I navigate to that URL in my browser I can confirm that it does not exist, it returns a 404 code.

What I don't understand is why `sbt` is trying to go to `spark-core_2.13` when the repository only lists `spark-core_2.12` as the latest dependency listed.

Is there something wrong with my `build.sbt` file? Is there a way to tell SBT to go to an arbitrary path for that dependency only?

Comment: The ```%%``` in the dependency automatically appends the scala version to your import. Do ```org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "2.4.5" ``` to prevent that

Comment: Because you asked it to do so. Set your scala version to `2.12.10`

Comment: @sinanspd That would only create a lot of binary incompatibilities.

Answer (score 7):

your scala version  `scalaVersion := "2.13.1"`  is the culprit.

since you have above scala version and your dependency is

```
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
```

so it s trying to find out spark-core 2.4.5 artifact compiled with 2.13 and its not existing....

see here for scala spark version compatablity

[Spark runs on Java 8, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.5 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x).](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#downloading)

see mvn repo as well [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/2.4.5)

if you change it to 2.12 it will work.

I think there is no spark version which is compatible with scala 2.13.
see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core)

[image]